# Heroku stops running?

Tags: python, heroku

I created a discord bot with python that would send messages and I used heroku to have the bot up 24/7. It was working fine for a week, then suddenly the bot stops working. Now, I can see that the bot is online on discord, but no messages are sent. When I write the command on the command line below, the log shows this. What does this mean and how do I fix this?

```
heroku logs -a <name-of-server>
```

Log:

```
2020-10-30T18:36:02.819434+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-10-30T18:36:04.245546+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-10-30T18:36:04.570255+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-10-30T18:36:05.938116+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot.py`
2020-10-30T18:36:06.602247+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-10-31T18:46:23.257340+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Cycling
```

Also, this log also repeats on and on from the time it stopped working. The wierd thing is that the bot is still online 24/7, but it just hasnt sent any messages.

Comment: What is your dyno container plan?

Comment: Oh its free. Is that why?

Comment: what your profic

Comment: @adam he's running a `worker` dyno. Not a `web` dyno. A `web` dyno goes to sleep after 30 minutes of web traffic inactivity. A `worker` dyno does not. [See here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping).

Comment: @Peter free dyno restarts every 24 hours, [see here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting)

Comment: okay, my bad. I will delete the misinformation. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @TinNguyen however, it doesnt seem to work anymore. It was working perfectly fine for a few weeks until it just stopped working.